# Strictly increasing, strictly concave function $f(x)$ defined for all $x$

Tags: functions

Is there a function with the above properties that can be written in a nice, closed form? I'm trying to think of an example and I'm at a loss. I've thought about starting with an equation for a line and getting it to bow out just a little, or starting with a logarithm and somehow removing the asymptote, but I don't know how to do either of those things. I'm just trying to model that situation using a simple function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example is $f(x)=-e^{-x}$.

Comment: An example where the range of the function is $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @AttilatheFun $g(x)=x-e^{-x}$

Comment: An example with no asymptotes? (This is good training in precision, because each of the responses is exactly what I asked for but not exactly what I had in mind).

Comment: Take $f(x)=\sinh^{-1} x$ for $x\ge 0$ and  $f(x)=\sinh x$ for $x\le 0$. This function is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ and has the properties you want. I am sure there is a smooth one as well.